# gaming under ubuntu logo

Tags: games, logo

I am about to create e-sport gaming team. It is possible to use ***ubuntu*** logo and/or name in it? like Ubuntu Gaming squad or something like that? Who shall I ask for that? We don't want to break some rules or copyright stuff.

Thanks for your advices in forward.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Canonical’s Trademarks (registered in word and logo form) include:

```
UBUNTU
KUBUNTU
EDUBUNTU
XUBUNTU
JUJU
LANDSCAPE
```

You can use the Trademarks, in accordance with Canonical’s brand guidelines, with Canonical’s permission in writing. If you require a Trademark licence, please contact us (as set out below).

You cannot use the Trademarks in software titles. If you are producing software for use with or on Ubuntu you may reference Ubuntu, but must avoid: (i) any implication of endorsement, or (ii) any attempt to unfairly or confusingly capitalise on the goodwill of Canonical or Ubuntu.